# How to record fixed number of samples in gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio

Is it possible to set a gnuradio flowgraph to record with a File Sink a fixed number of samples? I would like to use this wave as a reference.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An epy block is a good solution.
It can be connected where the desired data flows and collect the desired samples.
Then, a pressed push button can trigger the save.